# Priority queue pop elements according to values from another list in Java

Tags: java

I am making a transition from Python to Java, still in a process of getting myself familiarize with Java syntax. I am studying on priority queue (analogy in Python `heapq`) and not sure about some implementations, seems like I need to make a comparator in order to use it.

Suppose I have a queue

```
Queue<Object> buffer;

// for example, pop buffer element according to `element.value`
// this is not the accurate code but helps illustrate my points
BufferElement0.value() // return 5
BufferElement1.value() // return 3
BufferElement2.value() // return 7
```

What I want

```
buffer.poll() // return buffer element 2
buffer.poll() // return buffer element 0
buffer.poll() // return buffer element 1
```

that is, a series of values (int) have attached to each buffer element. How could I pop buffer element according to these given values?

**Update**

the Object is not necessary a number, suppose the object is

```
public class Message {

    public final double timeStamp;
    public final String text;
    public final Topic topic;
    public final Status status;
    public final int value;

    public Message(double timeStamp, String text, Topic topic, Status status, int value) {
        this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
        this.text = text;
        this.topic = topic;
        this.status = status;
        this.value = value;
    }


Queue<Message> msgs;
message = msgs.poll()
```

can we pop a `messsage` according to the `value` of that `message`?

Comment: please provide an example input and expected result to better illustrate your intention.

Comment: It is still unclear to me what you are trying to do here.

Comment: The most confusing explanation I have seen today

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so you want then Auto-sorted by value.

```
@Test
public void thing() throws Exception {
    Queue<Integer> queue = new PriorityQueue<>();
    queue.add(5);
    queue.add(3);
    queue.add(7);

    for(Integer thing = queue.poll(); thing != null; thing = queue.poll()) {
        System.out.println(thing);

    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
3
5
7
```

This works for things that are naturally sortable (AKA: Implement the `Comparable<?>` interface). However, even if they don't, you can define your own comparator and supply it to the constructor. Or, if it's one of your own objects you can implement `Comparable<T>` on it. In your case, you're using numbers which are naturally sortable.